# Integer to Boolean

Tags: python, integer, int, boolean

I'm new to python and I pray that I'm not bashed for this question... As a computer science major I feel it's only right to ask at least ONE question on stackoverflow.

How do I use an integer value as a boolean without the use of functions? Here's the question:

You will be given a series of mathematical and logical tasks.  Implement these
ONLY using variables and operators.  No loops, conditionals, functions or data
structures should be used.  You will only be working with the basic data
types: Integer, Float, String, and Boolean.

Operators that you can use:
       +, -, *, /, %, **, //,
       ==, !=, <>, >, <, >=, <=,
       =, +=, -=, *=, /=, %=, **=, //=,
       and, or, not,
       &, |, ^, ~, <<, >>

Given:

a = 5

b = 7

Task: Implement xor (abbreviation for 'exclusive or'). Xor should be true if a
       and b are not the same. Store the value of a xor b in a variable named
       output.
       Example: 2 xor 9 = True

I know it would be extremely easy to do:
output = bool(a^b)

However... I can't use functions :/

a^b=12 which is a true value... I just don't know how to get that to represent a boolean value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't overthink it.

```
return a != b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really like that operator:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 9
>>> output = True if a^b else False
>>> output
True
```

or more simply:

```
output = a != b
```

Comment: @flornquake: Thanks.  And I hadn't thought I was tired, either! ;)